# How do I get a US credit or debit card if I reside outside the US?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, bank-account, online-payment

I am from Hungary and I would like to purchase sometimes from US web services like iTunes and so on. They require US cards and billing address. Is it possible to have one without traveling to the US? If not, how can I open a bank account in the US what information is needed?

Comment: With regard to iTunes specifically, the following might be of interest. I wanted to buy an iTunes gift card (available at many retail outlets in the US) as a gift for a family member who resides in India. The fine print said that the iTunes card could only be used to download music to a computer with a US IP address and could not be used with IP addresses in other countries.

Answer (score 1):

Get a prepaid card.

Comment: How do I get one? Can you please recommend me a bank that do this kind of stuff?

Comment: You can buy prepaid cards all over the place in the U.S. and Canada.  For instance, at the local drug store / pharmacy, we can buy prepaid Mastercard and Visa in denominations like $25, $50, $100 etc.  If you ever visit the U.S. or Canada you can buy them in person at such a store.  I'm not sure of an online source, but there is probably one.  Just be careful who you buy from, as usual.

Comment: If the site insists on a US billing address and a US card, a prepaid card may not help much. On the other hand, since gift cards now-a-days are prepaid cards, maybe the online merchants will accept them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=us%20bank%20debit%20card%20non%20us%20citizen&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb) ? Not asking this to be rude but since the first link for me gives instructions on how to get a US Card - the downside is that if you wish a debt/credit card they seem to require that you deposit $1000 :(

Another option that should work is to open an iTunes account with a US address and then add credits to that account with gift cards (you can find these at for instance ebay) - I have not tried this myself, but I know of a few friends that have done this for there apple tv to get US shows on them (here in Sweden).

Comment: US addresses are not working anymore. They somehow figure out that the credit card is not US based. Although the gift card seems to be a nice trick! I might try it :)